# Is it possible to use an open generic as constructor argument?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

I created a *very* simple event publisher and it looks like this.

```
public class EventPublisher
{
    private readonly IList<Func<IHandle>> _subscribers;

    public EventPublisher(IList<Func<IHandle>> subscribers)
    {
        _subscribers = subscribers;
    }

    public void Publish<TPayload>(TPayload payload)
        where TPayload : class
    {
        var payloadHandlers = _subscribers.OfType<Func<IHandle<TPayload>>>();

        foreach (var payloadHandler in payloadHandlers)
        {
            payloadHandler().Handle(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have to publish messages.

```
var subscribers = new List<Func<IHandle>> {() => new SomeHandler()};
var eventPublisher = new EventPublisher(subscribers);

eventPublisher.Publish(new SomeMessage { Text = "Some random text..." });
```

The issue I'm having is that publishing a message isn't finding any handlers that can handle the payload. This makes sense because I registered my subscribers as `Func<IHandle>` instead of `Func<IHandle<T>>`.

The interface my handler classes are inheriting from is from Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator and it looks like this.

```
public interface IHandle {}

public interface IHandle<TMessage> : IHandle {
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

What must the type of `_subscribers` be to handle the `IHandle<>` where the generic type can be any concrete type?

Comment: If you're still using Windsor, you might benefit from using that to instantiate the handlers. It has inbuilt support for such scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 4, I'd expect this to work:

```
var subscribers = new List<Func<IHandle<SomeMessage>>> {() => new SomeHandler()};
```

then to get covariance:

```
public EventPublisher(IEnumerable<Func<IHandle>> subscribers)
{
    _subscribers = subscribers.ToList();
}
```

That lets you subscribe with any sequence of things compatible with `Func<IHandle>`. Note that it *does* change the semantics significantly, in that the set of subscribers will be fixed after construction. Personally I'd regard that as a good thing, but it may not suit you.

Alternatively, does the `EventPublisher` itself have to work with multiple types? Could you make it `EventPublisher<T>` and use `IHandle<T>` everywhere, making `Publish` non-generic? This may or may not be feasible based on how you want to use this - both options make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot to add the tag for C# 3.5. Is something similar possible with .NET 3.5? `EventPublisher` only works with types that inherit `IHandle<>`.

Comment: @gcso: No, without .NET 4 you'll have problems. (It's .NET 3.5, not C# 3.5, btw - the version of C# that comes with .NET 3.5 is C# 3.0.) Can you make EventPublisher generic instead? That would be simpler...

Comment: Thanks, Jon. That must be why I couldn't find a c#3.5 tag. :D

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing. An open generic cannot be statically compiled/linked. It has a real type (`typeof(IHandle<>)`), but you can only operate on it using reflection.

The best you can do is to store then as `object` (or `dynamic` in .NET 4), or as a common base type `IHandle` as you've done, but either way, you will not have compile time access to the `Handle` event. You'll have to use Reflection or casting to invoke it at runtime.

To bind the events in the first place, you could take advantage of the type inference in a *method* (*not* constructor), i.e.

```
public void RegisterHandler(IHandle<TMessage> handler) { ... }
```

Method calls can be written without the generic argument as long as you pass in a valid generic `IHandle<TMessage>` as a parameter.  You can use this to restrict what goes into your collection of non-generic `IHandle` objects, and then use Reflection methods (specifically the `GetInterfaces`, `GetMethod` and `MakeGenericMethod` methods) to actually invoke the handler. Or, as in your example, if you already know the event type, then just attempt a cast.